# On Bing Ads Api how can I convert the results to Json or Xml?

Tags: python, json, xml, bing, bing-api

I am using the Python Api for Bing Ads, I would like to store all campaigns, ads, etc in a database, and from now and then synchronize with bing ads. I would like to store the campaigns for example in DB, in xml or json format, so basically serialize the object.

So if I try to do:

```py
json.dumps(campaign)
# TypeError: Object of type Campaign is not JSON serializable
```

I read on stackoverflow to try something like this:

```py
json.dumps(campaign.__dict__)
# TypeError: Object of type __printer__ is not JSON serializable
```

So I started removing the properties of the object that are not serializable, but that doesn't sound right, there must be a more elegant way..

After different attempts this is more and less what I have tried

```py
        campaigns = campaign_service.GetCampaignsByAccountId(
            AccountId=account_id,
            CampaignType=bc.ALL_CAMPAIGN_TYPES)

        for campaign in campaigns['Campaign']:
            dir(campaign)
            if campaign.Id is None:
                continue
            print(campaign.__printer__.tostr())
            exit()
            # delattr(campaign.__dict__, "ManualCpcBiddingScheme")
            delattr(campaign, "__metadata__")
            delattr(campaign, "__printer__")
            print(campaign.__dict__)
            rows.append(json.dumps(campaign.__dict__))
            exit()
            print(rows)
            exit()
```

Unfortunately I cannot find any "native" method from bing, toxml or tojson.
Furthermore Bing is not so popular in terms of API so there isn't much information online.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own `json.JSONEncoder` which will take care of the special fields like `__printer__`

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

See https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/576/json.JSONEncoder for examples